# node unable to join a galera cluster; it fails during state transfer

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xtradb-cluster

It looks like the node is joining the cluster and then it fails… I have tried with both rsync and xtrabackup and it fails during state transfer. I seems to me that I am missing something real simple and I am not able to put a finger on it.. Any help would be appreciated.

More information regarding the nodes

Master - 10.XXX.XXX.161 
node1 - 10.XXX.XXX.160

Packages installed:
MariaDB-compat MariaDB-common MariaDB-devel MariaDB-shared MariaDB-client MariaDB-test MariaDB-Galera-server (v5.5.29-1)
galera (v23.2.4-1.rhel6)
percona-xtrabackup (v2.1.6-702.rhel6)

config for node 1

```
[mysqld]
wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://10.XXX.XXX.161
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options = gcache.size=4G; gcache.page_size=1G
wsrep_cluster_name = galera_cluster
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth = root:rootpassword
wsrep_node_name=1
```

config for master

```
[mysqld]
wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options = gcache.size=4G; gcache.page_size=1G
wsrep_cluster_name = galera_cluster
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
wsrep_sst_method = rsync
wsrep_slave_threads = 4
wsrep_sst_auth = root:rootpassword
wsrep_node_name = 2
```

node1 log file

```
131203 16:09:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131203 16:09:03 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error=/tmp/tmp.f2EedjRjbQ
131203 16:09:08 mysqld_safe WSREP: Recovered position 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2188
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position var submitted: '359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2188'
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 23.2.4(r147) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com]]> loaded succesfully.
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Reusing existing '/var/lib/mysql//galera.cache'.
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = 10.XXX.XXX.160; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 1G; gcache.size = 4G; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = NO; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = NO; replicator.causal_read_timeout = PT30S; replicator.commit_order = 3
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: (8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: (8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: PC version 0
131203 16:09:08 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'galera_cluster', peer '10.XXX.XXX.161:'
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: declaring 7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a stable
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Node 7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a state prim
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,2) memb {
     7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,
     8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'galera_cluster'
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 2
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515 from 0 (2)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515 from 1 (1)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
     version    = 2,
     component  = PRIMARY,
     conf_id    = 1,
     members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
     act_id     = 2521,
     last_appl. = -1,
     protocols  = 0/4/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
     group UUID = 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 2521)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
     Group state: 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2521
     Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2521, view# 2: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 1, protocol version 2
131203 16:09:09 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address '10.XXX.XXX.160' --auth 'root:rootpassword' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '13175''
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: xtrabackup|10.162.143.160:4444/xtrabackup_sst
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 2521, protocol version: 2
131203 16:09:11 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd): 1 (Operation not permitted)
      at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():442. IST will be unavailable.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Node 1 (1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0 (2)(SYNCED) as donor.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 2525)
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
tar: dbexport/db.opt: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: 0 (2): State transfer to 1 (1) complete.
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Member 0 (2) synced with group.
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Error while getting st data from donor node:  0, 2 (20131203 16:10:22.379)
131203 16:10:22 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'joiner' --address '10.XXX.XXX.160' --auth 'root:rootpassword' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '13175': 32 (Broken pipe)
131203 16:10:22 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno from joiner script.
131203 16:10:22 [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 32 (Broken pipe)
131203 16:10:22 [ERROR] Aborting
131203 16:10:24 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
131203 16:10:24 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
131203 16:10:24 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
131203 16:10:24 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
131203 16:10:24 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,2) memb {
     8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
     7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,
})
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = no, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Received NON-PRIMARY.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINER -> OPEN (TO: 2607)
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> CLOSED (TO: 2607)
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: rollbacker thread exiting
131203 16:10:26 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
131203 16:10:26 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 2 threads didn't exit
131203 16:10:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

master log file

```
131203 16:08:47 [Warning] Recovery from master pos 103358630 and file mysql-bin.000131.
131203 16:08:47 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131203 16:08:47 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:08:47 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 2497, protocol version: 2
131203 16:08:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.29-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server, wsrep_23.7.3.rXXXX
131203 16:08:47 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
131203 16:08:47 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: declaring 8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96 stable
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Node 7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a state prim
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,2) memb {
     7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,
     8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 2
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515 from 0 (2)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 8861cdd5-5c67-11e3-0800-cc70fcc5f515 from 1 (1)
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
     version    = 2,
     component  = PRIMARY,
     conf_id    = 1,
     members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
     act_id     = 2521,
     last_appl. = 2517,
     protocols  = 0/4/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
     group UUID = 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2521, view# 2: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 0, protocol version 2
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:09:09 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 2521, protocol version: 2
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Node 1 (1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0 (2)(SYNCED) as donor.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> DONOR/DESYNCED (TO: 2525)
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup --role 'donor' --address '10.XXX.XXX.160:4444/xtrabackup_sst' --auth 'root:rootpassword' --socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --gtid '359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2525''
131203 16:09:11 [Note] WSREP: sst_donor_thread signaled with 0
131203 16:10:20 [Note] WSREP: Provider paused at 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2604
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Provider resumed.
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: 0 (2): State transfer to 1 (1) complete.
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Shifting DONOR/DESYNCED -> JOINED (TO: 2606)
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Member 0 (2) synced with group.
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 2606)
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
131203 16:10:22 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Node 7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a state prim
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,3) memb {
     7a9a87e8-5c67-11e3-0800-8cb6cba8f65a,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
     8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96,
})
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: forgetting 8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96 (tcp://10.XXX.XXX.160:4567)
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: b5dda52e-5c67-11e3-0800-4b2360dd84f9
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: b5dda52e-5c67-11e3-0800-4b2360dd84f9
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: b5dda52e-5c67-11e3-0800-4b2360dd84f9 from 0 (2)
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
     version    = 2,
     component  = PRIMARY,
     conf_id    = 2,
     members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
     act_id     = 2607,
     last_appl. = 2597,
     protocols  = 0/4/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
     group UUID = 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 359350ee-5c63-11e3-0800-6673d15135cd:2607, view# 3: Primary, number of nodes: 1, my index: 0, protocol version 2
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
131203 16:10:25 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 2607, protocol version: 2
131203 16:10:30 [Note] WSREP:  cleaning up 8814b4ba-5c67-11e3-0800-91035d554a96 (tcp://10..XXX.XXX.160:4567)
```

Comment: Suspicious: `tar: dbexport/db.opt: Cannot open: Permission denied` ... do you have a schema called "dbexport"?

Comment: Try giving in my.cnf for all nodes as `wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3`

where node1=192.168.1.1 and node2=192.168.1.2 etc..

Comment: dbexport is a folder which houses my nightly mysql backup. I deleted the entire folder out of frustration and it worked (I took backup before deleting). I put backups in /var/lib/mysql/dbexport, My datadir attribute is /var/lib/mysql, so this might be a stupid question, why did galera even try to touch that?

Answer (score 1):

Galera cluster is a quorum-based system, Galera cluster is subject to split-brain condition when quorum algorithm fails to select a primary component. This can happen, for example, in a cluster without the backup switch if the main switch fails. But the most likely split brain situation is when single node fails in a two-node cluster. Thus it is strongly advised that the minimum Galera cluster configuration is 3 nodes. In the state transfer section below we will consider one more reason why 3 is the minimum recommended number of nodes.

So, make sure that you have

> wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3 #where node1=192.168.1.1 and node2=192.168.1.2 etc.

on all nodes and restart one-by-one all nodes after this change

A typical `my.cnf` for Galera cluster should be like this:
http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=mysql_galera_configuration

I hope this information helps

Comment: Reference: http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=info

Comment: thanks for the info, I already knew all this. I was planning to connect the nodes one at a time...considering all the trouble I was having on forming a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem here; nodes 2 and 3 were Partitioned on Node 1, and when we tried to bring them up, the SST failed (there had been a huge amount of DB updates and so the 300M gcache had already rolled over and an IST was not possible).

The solution was to restart node 1, which cleared the WSREP node stated; then start up node 2, which did a (very long) SST and came up OK.  Then bring up node 3 in a similar manner, and all 3 up and members.

However this solution means a brief service (<1min) outage as the main node is restarted, which may not be acceptable.

I have yet to find a way to clean out a down node's 'partitioned' status on the surviving node without a restart.

Like you, we are using Percona Xtrabackup for the WSREP.  I believe that the problem lies in this requiring a database connection; if using rsync then the SST may complete as expected.